# Magento2 Filter shipping method based on Order Total and Country Selected

Tags: magento2, shipping, filter

I want to filter shipping method in magento2 as below given manner.

```
Case1: If the Order total is less than $75 and the country is USA display Flat Rate Shipping $7

case2: If the Order total is greater than $75 and the country is USA display Free Shipping

case3: If the country is other than the USA no matter whatever is ordered total display Table Rate Shipping $30
```

But at a given time checkout page should display only one of the above shipping based on the conditions.

Any help should be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The WebShopApps_MatrixRate extension, which is free and has been around for quite some time, will do this. It is based on the native Magento table rate shipping method.

You can upload a csv containing specific conditions including location and price and present shipping options based on the conditions met.

Comment: @Shawam Abramson: Sure I will try this extension but I would just like to know that it will take the conditions like I have explained ?

Comment: Yes. Here is a link to the configuration docs. It explains how you would configure your csv. http://support.webshopapps.com/matrixrate/destination-shipping-rule-logic/

Comment: @Shawam Abramson: Thanks for the help I will check and let you know.

Comment: @Shawam Abramson: I have tried to create the CSV file and import but it is not working. More over I try to create CSV file with price  and when I again export that csv file my price column will be converted to weight. ?

Comment: You might be doing something wrong. At my full time, we use this extension quite frequently, and in a way similar to what you are wanting. I'd recommend keep checking the docs/examples, not sure what else to say, but it will work.

Comment: They might also be kind enough to respond if you submit a ticket.

Comment: It is giving error like this " We couldn't import this file because of these errors: Please correct Shipping Price "*" in Row #2."

Comment: I have resolved the issue in the condition when you want to filter out shipping methods based on order total at that you are required to select Condition input to Order Subtotal V/s Destination. But still thanks much for providing the link of the this extension which had help me a lot.

Comment: My pleasure and good luck with your project!

Comment: Yes and I have up voted your answer as well.. Thanks !

Comment: There is also another useful extension https://owebia.com/doc/en/magento2-module-advanced-shipping#hints_method_chaining#examples_using_destination